# Mock server problem while testing with Jest and apollo-server

Tags: tcp, jestjs, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server, jest and graphql
I'm going to post all of my codes first:

**mockServer.ts**

```
export const startMockServer = async () => {
  await server.listen()
}
export const stopMockServer = async () => {
  await server.stop()
}
```

**example.test.ts**

```
describe('Testing example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await startMockServer()
  })

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await dbHelper.connect()
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await dbHelper.clearDatabase()
  })
  afterAll(async () => {
    await stopMockServer()
    await dbHelper.closeDatabase()
  })

//it test here
//it test here
```

**company.test.ts**

```
describe('Testing company', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await startMockServer()
  })

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await dbHelper.connect()
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await dbHelper.clearDatabase()
  })
  afterAll(async () => {
    await stopMockServer()
    await dbHelper.closeDatabase()
  })
//it test here
//it test here
```

Okay here is the problem: When I run `npm test`, it runs `jest --forceExit`. However, it throws `EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000`. From what I understand, the server in `afterAll` closes after it finishes testing the `example.test.ts`. When it starts testing `company.test.ts`, it start a new server with the same port 4000. But the problem occurs because port 4000 is in TIME_WAIT (whatever that is) so it counts that the port is in use.

Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `apollo-server-testing` so now I don't have to deal with this whole ordeal.